# Could not load type 'SqlGuidCaster' from assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5'

Tags: .net-8.0, system.data.sqlclient

I created a blank webapi project for .NET8,Install two packages Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel,Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
The following is the source code：
`using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel;    using System.Reflection;    using System.Runtime.Loader;    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);    var list = DependencyContext.Default.RuntimeLibraries.ToList();    var assemblies = list.Select(m =>{ try { return AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyName(new AssemblyName(m.Name)); }catch { return null; } }).Where(m => m != null).ToList();    foreach (var assembly in assemblies) {foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes()) { } }     app.Run();`

After compilation, an error message such as the title will be prompted.
This does not exist in .NET6.
A similar error will occur when changing Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to System.Data.SqlClient
How to solve it? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 9):

This is due to a bug in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and as mentioned [here](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1930#issuecomment-1842493401), the workaround for now seems to be to update the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient NuGet package to the latest preview version, which is currently v5.2.0-preview3.23201.1.
I had the same issue and can confirm, that this workaround is working.

Comment: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient v5.2.0 has been released last week, so no need for the workaround with the preview version anymore, just update to the latest version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.